# How to extract content that is sent to a PrintStream?

Tags: java

Im using a thirdparty class that has the following method:

```
public void print(PrintStream s);
```

But what I want to do is acually log the output. SOmething like:

```
RecordingPrintStream p = new RecordingPrintStream
instance.print(p);
logger.log(p.getContents());
```

So what can I use as my RecordingPrintStream?

Comment: Are you asking for an existing class, or do you want to know how to implement RecordingPrintStream?

Comment: The former. As a last resort I could subclass PrintStream and override all the output methods, but I'd rather not, obviously.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PrintStream recordingStream = new PrintStream(baos);
instance.print(recordingStream);
logger.log(baos.toString());
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use following contructor to create PrintStream :
PrintStream(OutputStream out)

You can use any of StringOutputStream while Creating Printstream object, And get contents from StringBuffer to output with your log method.

```
class StringOutputStream extends OutputStream {

  StringBuilder mBuf;

  public void write(int byte) throws IOException {
    mBuf.append((char) byte);
  }

  public String getString() {
    return mBuf.toString();
  }
}
```

So if you want to output to file you use object of FileOutputStream while constructing PrintStream object.

Comment: But that will circumvent the logging mechanism and just go straight to the logfile.

Comment: you can't do `mBuf.append((char) byte)` and expect any meaningful output from the toString(). Characters are not bytes in java.